# Reduce storage space needed in Nodejs/Expressjs/Feathersjs for the user ID

Tags: node.js, express, feathersjs

I am working on my first nodejs based project using Feathersjs as a backend and Vue as frontend. When I look in the database then the user ID is a character string looking something like this: "IXS1rCoGogkdOOss".

This seems like it will use more storage space than needed, when a integer user id would suffice.

Can the storage space requirement be reduced somehow?

Perhaps by having the user ID stored as an integer in the database instead of a text string?

I have tried to look through the code but I can not find where the user ID assignment occurs. I am new to both javascipt and node.js and I just can't get my head around this. Searching this site and googling also turned up nothing.

And the reason why it seems like a good idea to reduce the storage size of the user ID is that this will be a multi tenant SaaS with less than 10k users but close to a billion rows containing the user ID.

Thanks for the help!

**Edit**

I will be using Postgres in production, but have been using NeDB to try things out initially.

The tables with many rows in them consists of 3 int values plus the primary key (which is a int + user ID).

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention that. I am using NeDB for learning how to use these frameworks but the production site will be using Postgres. Daff's answer below made me understand that I will need to switch to Postgres to really test this thing properly. (facepalm)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This depends entirely on the database you are using. [MongoDB](https://docs.feathersjs.com/api/databases/mongodb.html), [Mongoose](https://docs.feathersjs.com/api/databases/mongoose.html) use [MongoDB ObjectIds](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/ObjectId/) and [NeDB](https://docs.feathersjs.com/api/databases/nedb.html) uses a similar value. For those databases it is not trivial to change the primary id to something else.

An SQL database - which can be used through the [Sequelize](https://docs.feathersjs.com/api/databases/sequelize.html) or [KnexJS](https://docs.feathersjs.com/api/databases/knexjs.html) adapters - usually uses integers as the primary key.

In the grand scheme of things if your database entries consist of anything more than a single other value, the number of characters in the id property does not really matter that much when it comes to actual size though.

Comment: Thanks! I am using NeDB for testing (learning how this nodejs thingy works), but the production site will be using Postgres. I will try with Postgres and see if the ID changes automagically. The tables with lots of rows in them consists of 3 int values plus the primary key.

Comment: I used the feathers postgres example https://github.com/raganw/feathers-postgresql and it created the user ID as an int. Solved! Thank you so much for the quick and to the point answer!